# Ошибка установки плагина ADT для Eclipse не Windows

Tags: windows, android, eclipse

На чистую Windows Vista установлены

- JDK 7u2
- Eclipse SDK 3.7.1

При попытке установки плагина ADT для Eclipse, выдается следующая ошибка:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
>   Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Как исправить? (На Linux все всегда было нормально).

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась сама после запуском Eclipse с правами администратора.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.
Странно, что самому не пришло в голову. Просто с Комодо и НетБинс до этого рутовых прав не требовалось.